# is there any alternative for maven reactor plugin?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

is there any plugin which works like maven reactor plugin ?
or is there any plugin available in Apache maven which builds an ear project through pom.xml and all of its dependent jar/war files automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reactor arguments are part of Maven core nowadays. See `mvn -h` (below reactor related options)

```
Options:
-am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                    build projects required by the
                                    list
-amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                    build projects that depend on
-h,--help                              Display help information
-pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                    reactor projects to build instead
-rf,--resume-from <arg>                Resume reactor from specified
                                    project
                                    of all projects. A project can be
                                    specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                    or by its relative path.
```

Answer (score 0):

See  [Maven, POM Reference, Maven Coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates):

> - **packaging**:
>
>   The current core packaging values are: ..., `jar`, ..., `war`, `ear`, ...

See also [Maven, Introduction to Archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html):

> **Provided Archetypes**
>
> | maven-archetype-j2ee-simple | An archetype to generate a simplifed sample J2EE application.
>
> | maven-archetype-webapp | An archetype to generate a sample Maven Webapp project.