# How can I configure Bamboo to just build the module containing the change, rather than the entire project?

Tags: maven, bamboo

We have a multi module Maven project configured in Bamboo.
Currently, when someone checks a change into Gitlab, the entire project rebuilds.

Is there a direct way to configure Bamboo to just build the module containing the change, rather than the entire project?

I saw information about the Maven Reactor plugin here [is there any alternative for maven reactor plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554115/is-there-any-alternative-for-maven-reactor-plugin) but it seems that is retired. In any case, I am not sure how to configure that in Bamboo.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but isn't your CI server for CI intended which means build the whole project and run all test to see if a checkin breaks something ?

Comment: Good point. We will run a master build every night, but mostly the changes are independent, so we want to capture any coverage or other static analysis issues early

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need separate plans to build the different modules but you could setup a linked repository for each module that triggers a build on matching a file pattern.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-Bamboo-build-on-changes-to-a/qaq-p/247407

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO052/_planRepositoryIncludeExcludeFilesExamples?_ga=2.25234749.1479403392.1517319627-1365240128.1480009251

Comment: I see, so one project with modules in Git, separate build plans for each module, then trigger each build separately based on the module location